# Max AWS SQS Queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Does anyone know what the maximum amount of queues I can create is? I've look around on AWS and can't seem to find the answer. I might have almost 50 different queues at the end of this project and want to make sure I am not running out of runway...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no limit for the number of queues:

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Limits_and_restrictions

> Q: How many message queues can I create?
>
> You can create any number of message queues.

There is also no limit for the number of messages in a queue:

> Q: How large can Amazon SQS message queues be?
>
> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an unlimited number of messages. However, there is a quota of 120,000 for the number of inflight messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue. Messages are inflight after they have been received from the queue by a consuming component, but have not yet been deleted from the queue.

Comment: A good example why an answer should not only link to a URL but state the relevant part. The updated FAQ (5 Jan 2017) states: **Q: How large can Amazon SQS message queues be?**: A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an unlimited number of messages. However, there is a 120,000 limit for the number of inflight messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue.

Comment: @scheffield I'd edit the answer and cite the excerpt but this simply doesn't say how many queues are allowed... Only how many message per queue. So this just doesn't answer the question...

Comment: That anchor doesn't go anywhere specific, and the FAQ page is huge. However, right underneath the question @scheffield mentions (at least as of right now) , it says `Q: How many message queues can I create?`: `"You can create any number of message queues"`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any limit. We're currently running about 45 queues and I'm sure we hit the 50 queue limit a while ago.

Comment: the only "50" limit i can think of is pagination option on AWS console. How many queues to view at once per page. But not the limit of how many queues you can actually have. You can create unlimited amount of queues in single aws account.