# Auto Delete SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to auto delete SQS queues entirely. I have a solution wherein a server on startup creates an SQS and subscribes to SNS topic.

However there maybe scenarios wherein the server crashes and is irrecoverable. In such cases, I would replace the server with a different one which would create its own queue on startup. Now the earlier queue is not going to be used anymore.

Is there a way to for the queue to get auto-deleted with me going and deleting it explicitly (maybe like if the queue remains empty for 5 days, it gets auto deleted or some other alternative)?

Comment: Consider using CloudFormation to deploy your SQS queue, SNS topic, EC2 instance and whatever else you need for this workload. When you decide it's time to launch a new server, because you've detected problems with the old server, simply delete the old CloudFormation stack and create a new stack.

Comment: if I understanding your answer correctly: would I not even in that case need to manually go about deleting old CloudFormation stack.

Comment: You've indicated that you have to replace the existing server. That's an explicit decision with manual intervention, presumably. I'm saying replace that process by one that deletes the old stack and creates a new one (in one step). If you really prefer not to do that, then you could put a launch-time script (in userdata) on the new EC2 instance and it could delete remnants of the old deployment (based on tags, or some other way to identify the things it needs to delete).

Comment: Another alternative is to use Auto Scaling to ensure that you always have one, and only one, healthy server. Set up health checks correctly, and Auto Scaling will kill the unhealthy server, and launch a new one (using the same SQS queue and SNS topic). Wrap this in a CloudFormation template for ease of deployment. Not sure why you want to create a new queue every time you launch the EC2 instance -- wouldn't you risk losing messages?

Comment: An example where queues that clean themselves up is useful is automated integration testing. My test wants to work in its own sandbox, but for various reasons cleanup code at the end of tests doesn't always run.  Ideally, the queues would have a configuration that caused them to expire after some reasonable amount of time, as the OP suggested.

Comment: You can do something like a dead-man switch. You can have the server create the queue, and tag it with a name prefix that you can filter on and a TTL. Something like "Name": "My-Application-{guid}", "TTL": "{10 minutes from now}". 
Then you can start a background thread on the server to bump the TTL of the queue every 5 minutes. Separately, you can have a cloudwatch event every so often (or any sort of cron job) that searches for queues with prefix "My-Application-" and an expired TTL to delete them. When you can exit gracefully, delete the queue, but the TTL helps otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, AWS SQS does not provide a mechanism to automatically delete a queue when it is empty for a certain number of days. Even I feel like this is a needed feature. But there are ways to tackle this problem.

Mentioned below, are a few ways to delete the AWS SQS according to the scenario in your question. You can select which suits you the most.

1. Maintain a small **Database** Table which keeps the **mapping between the Server IP and Queue URL**. You can insert values into this table, when a server starts itself. Maintain a **Cloudwatch** Rule that will invoke a **Lambda**, which will go through the values in the table to see if the server is running or not (probably by a heartbeat). If a particular server is not running, simply get the related **SQS URL** and **delete that specific Queue**. (I have suggested Lambda here because it is cheap)

> sqs.deleteQueue(new DeleteQueueRequest(myQueueUrl));

2. Whenever a Server is started, it can send an **Email** to a person with the Server IP and SQS URL using **SNS**. Using a **CloudWatch Rule**, invoke a **Lambda** from time to time, and get all Instances, and check if any instance is down. If an instance is down, send an email to the relevant person using SNS, emailing that this server is down. It is semi-automatic, where the use can manually delete the queue after seeing the email.
3. Simply let the Empty queues be on its own. There is no limit as to how many queues can be made inside AWS. So why bother to delete them if that process is hard. Simply create new Queue as you go along. (See: [No Max number of SQS Queue Limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367090/4388776))

Comment: If the queue is subscribed to an SNS topic as OP suggests, there would be costs incurring because the orphaned queues would get filled with messages from SNS

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to auto-delete queues. You could use tags to mark resources connected (i.e. tag queues or other resources with their respective instance-id on creation), and use a simple script that would read the said tag and delete if that instance-id does not exist.

here is how to do it on cli:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/tag-queue.html

(I'm assuming that by server you mean EC2 instance. Ip could also be used)