# Max number of queues

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is there a limit on the number of queues you can create with AWS SQS?

This page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html doesn't state so one way or the other.

We're not looking to create thousands of the things but might dynamically create a good few dozen for a while then destroy them. I've come across unexpected limits with AWS before (only 4 transcoding pipelines - why?) so need to be sure on this.

Thanks for any advice.

AB

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no informations about that in the AWS documentation.

I don't think there is a limit on the queues number.
We are actually working with **28 fulltime Queues** on our infrastructure without any problem.

If at least you hit a limit, a simple AWS support ticket can increase it.
Just like the Ec2 Number limit increase process.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response :-) It was difficult to find but I just stumbled across another question that pointed to the answer. It's at https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#How_big_can_Amazon_SQS_queues_be and under "Q: How many message queues can I create?" it states "You can create any number of message queues." - well hidden but there. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702582/max-aws-sqs-queues?rq=1